# Show that $re^{i\theta} = se^{i\alpha} \implies \text{$r = s$ and $\theta = \alpha + 2\pi k$}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Show that if $r,s > 0$ are positive real numbers, and $\theta, \alpha$ are real numbers such that $re^{i\theta} = se^{i\alpha}$, then $r = s$ and $\theta = \alpha + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$.

$e^{i\theta}: = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$. Therefore,  $re^{i\theta} -se^{i\alpha} = (r\cos(\theta) + s\cos(\alpha)) + i (r\sin(\theta) + s\sin(\alpha)) = 0$. This implies that the real part and the imaginary part must be both zero. But, it is still insufficient to reach the conclusion. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Take absolute values on both sides to conclude that $r=s$. And the exponential has complex period $2\pi i$, so from there it follows that $i\theta = i\alpha+2k\pi i$. Divide by $i$ and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Clearly we have $r = 0 \iff s = 0$ and if $r=s=0$ the angles are not important. Assume now $r \ne 0$ and hence $s \ne 0$ and divide the complex numbers. We get
$$
1 = \frac{r}{s}e^{i[\theta - \alpha]}.
$$
Taking modulus, we see $|r/s|=1$ so $r=s$ since they are both positive. Now we are left with $1 = e^{i[\theta-\alpha]}$.

Can you finish it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all  $re^{i\theta} -se^{i\alpha} = (r\cos(\theta) - s\cos(\alpha)) + i (r\sin(\theta) - s\sin(\alpha)) = 0$.

Since, $re^{i\theta} = se^{i\alpha}$, taking modulus on both sides, and $|e^{i\theta}|=|e^{i\alpha}|=1 \implies r=s. $
Now $re^{i\theta} = se^{i\alpha} \implies e^{i\theta} = e^{i\alpha} \implies e^{i(\theta-\alpha)} = 1 \implies (\theta-\alpha)=2k\pi\implies \theta=2k\pi+\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $re^{i\theta}-se^{i\alpha}=(r\cos\theta-s\cos\alpha)+i(r\sin\theta-s\sin\alpha)=0$, (NOT "$+$"!) we have
$$
\begin{cases}
r\cos\theta-s\cos\alpha=0,\\
r\sin\theta-s\sin\alpha=0.
\end{cases}
$$

Since $rs\ne0$, then 
$$
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta &-\cos\alpha\\
\sin\theta &-\sin\alpha
\end{array}\right|=0\Rightarrow\sin(\theta-\alpha)=0\Rightarrow\theta=\alpha+2k\pi
$$

Apply it to the former quation, then $r=s$ can be obtained.